Unable to require and set up IAM users to use MFA
I am somewhat of an AWS/IAM noob, and I need to require all my users to use MFA in AWS AIM, but I am unable to find the setting to require that. If I follow a lot of the instructions I'm finding, it only walks me through setting it up on my own phone, not allowing my users to set it up. I did find these instructions, but when I go to my IAM Identity Center Console, there is no left nav with a Settings option, and I can't find this Configure multi-factor authentication page.
In the current IAM, where do I go to to find this Users can add and manage their own MFA devices setting? Or, is there a different place to do it now?

I was able to get this to work by creating the policy specified in the AWS docs and assigning it to the users.

To allow MFA-authenticated IAM users to manage their own MFA devices, you need to create and attach a specific IAM policy. This policy should allow users to perform MFA-related actions on their own IAM user resources. Here's how to do it:
Add Policy to Allow MFA-Authenticated Users to Manage Their Own MFA

Open the IAM Console:

Go to the AWS Management Console and open the IAM console at IAM Console.


Create a New Policy:

In the navigation pane, choose Policies.
Choose Create policy.
On the Create Policy page, switch to the JSON tab.


Add the Policy JSON:
Refer below official document from AWS for json policy
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage-mfa-only.html

Review and Create Policy:

Choose Review policy.
Provide a name and description for the policy, e.g., ManageOwnMFA.
Choose Create policy.



Attach the Policy to Users or Groups

Navigate to Users or Groups:

In the IAM console navigation pane, choose Users or Groups.
Select the user or group to which you want to attach the policy.


Attach the Policy:

Choose the Permissions tab.
Choose Add permissions.
Select Attach policies directly.
Search for the policy you created (ManageOwnMFA), select it, and choose Next: Review.
Choose Add permissions.



Verify Policy Effectiveness

Sign in as the User:

Have the user sign in to the AWS Management Console.


Navigate to My Security Credentials:

The user should click on their username in the navigation bar and select My Security Credentials.


Manage MFA Devices:

Under Multi-factor authentication (MFA), the user should be able to manage their MFA devices, including adding, enabling, and deleting their own MFA devices.



